# How to get facebook username from my friends list.?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the userNames of people in my friends list . How can i achieve that ?

I am using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends&access_token=...
```

This is returning me a `json response` with all the Name and IDnumber ? I want somehow to get the Username ( Not userID ) ?

There is one way that I access each ID and then get the userName but that will take so long considering I have 500 friends. Is there some shorter way / easier way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for the username in the fields parameter:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=username&access_token=...
```

Comment: It just works for users that have authorised your app.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find anything in the API to get a list of user profiles. But one possible solution is to use batch requests. You can combine each individual user profile request into one large batch. It's still cumbersome, but better than making a separate HTTP request for each friend.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/

For example:

```
  $batched_request = '[
    {"method":"GET","relative_url":"friend_id_1"},'.'{"method":"GET","relative_url":"friend_id_2"}
  ]';

  $post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch=" . $batched_request
  . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&method=post";
```